# Macro spacing mystery

Tags: spacing, macros

I get different spacing results when I define a \hspace directly or as a macro.

**Directly:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{Title}
\author{Daniel Domingues \hspace{0.2cm}$\diamond$\hspace{0.2cm} Ricardo Cruz \hspace{0.2cm}$\diamond$\hspace{0.2cm} Rui d'Orey}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: Case 1]

**As a macro:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\whatever{\hspace{0.2cm}$\diamond$\hspace{0.2cm}}

\title{Title}
\author{Daniel Domingues \whatever Ricardo Cruz \whatever Rui d'Orey}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: Case 2]

It looks better when I use \hspace directly without the macro. Why is that?

Comment: This is a FAQ and must be a duplicate. the space character after `\whatever` is absorbed as the terminator for the macro name so does not make a token.  the space character after `}` does make a token so produces a word space in addition to the stated space of .2cm.

Comment: It is usually best not to have a space before or after `\hspace`, looking at the source you might think there was .2cm of white space but there `s \hspace{.2cm} R` produces one inter-word space, .2cm space and one more inter-word space.

Comment: Rewrite the `\author` instruction as `\author{Daniel Domingues\whatever Ricardo Cruz\whatever Rui d'Orey}` -- note: no space before the two instances of `\whatever` -- and you'll less, but more even, spacing. OTOH, if you want *more* (as well as more even) spacing, write `\author{Daniel Domingues \whatever\ Ricardo Cruz \whatever  Rui d'Orey}`.

Comment: That was quick ! --- you guys are awesome, thank you!